# COUNT total by weekly and monthly SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in which I have to count total rows assigned to each USER by daily, weekly and monthly.

Table BooksIssued

```
BOOKID    ISSUEDUSER    DATE
 1            A        20160708
 2            A        20160709
 3            A        20160708
 4            A        20150102
 5            B        20160709
 6            C        20160708
 7            C        20160708
```

Now I have to COUNT daily, weekly and monthly books issued to each user

Daily is today (20160709)
Weekly is Sunday through Saturday
Monthly is whole month

The result should be

```
ISSUEDUSER    DAILYBOOKS WEEKLYBOOKS  MONTHLYBOOKS
  A               1       3           3
  B               1       1           1
  C               0       2           2
```

I have done this SQL for daily issued

```
SELECT ISSUEDUSER, COUNT(BOOKID) AS DAILYBOOKS
FROM BOOKSISSUED
WHERE DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), SYSDATETIME(), 112)
GROUP BY ISSUEDUSER
```

Can someone please help me write a **combined** SQL for all three ?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: Your table has stored Dates into integers...wow, that was thoughtless of them. DATE does not have a default format anyways.... :/

Comment: how does one know if they have a daily book rental? Is it repeated by BookID per day? Or are you just using the present day to calculate how many daily books (those under a week) and weekly books (those within several weeks?) and those by months?  A bit confused as to what you are wanting to see.

Comment: The books should be counted by CURRENT DAY, CURRENT WEEK (Sunday to Sat) and CURRENT MONTH only. Previousd and any other should not be counted and shown, The ID is not repeated.

Comment: As in your later comment  Or are you just using the present day to calculate how many daily books (those under a week). Only current week and current month. I just wnt to count that how many were issued.

Comment: check out my cool answer. :) `DATEPART` is a beast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might need to add a WHERE clause to only retrieve current month's records

```
SELECT ISSUEDUSER, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DAILYBOOKS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0)
                AND  DATE <  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()) + 1, 0)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WEEKLYBOOKS,
       COUNT(*) AS MONTHLYBOOKS
FROM   BOOKSISSUED
WHERE  DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0)
AND    DATE <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SYSDATETIME()) + 1, 0)
GROUP BY ISSUEDUSER
```

EDIT : for [DATE] column is INT

```
SELECT ISSUEDUSER, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), SYSDATETIME(), 112))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DAILYBOOKS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0), 112))
                AND  DATE <  CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()) + 1, 0), 112))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WEEKLYBOOKS,
       COUNT(*) AS MONTHLYBOOKS
FROM   BOOKSISSUED
WHERE  DATE >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), SYSDATETIME(), 112) + '01')
AND    DATE <  CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, SYSDATETIME()), 112) + '01')
GROUP BY ISSUEDUSER
```

Comment: Thanks a heap! I will now try and will comment :)

Comment: It says Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int. I think I need a cast here

Comment: SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()) gives date in  2016-07-09, I have to use 11 to format it in yyyMMdd format

Comment: Can you please tell where to add WHERE to get only current month's records ?-

Comment: edited the query. Added the `WHERE` and change the `MONTHLYBOOKS` to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Thanks! This part  DATE = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME) gives error as said above, I converted it to CONVERT(char(10), CREATIONDATE,126)  = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME())

Comment: oh .. you must be using SQL 2008 or earlier. i will update the query

Comment: Thanks, the date is INT and format in database is yyyyMMdd and the query returned in yyyy-mm-dd, that is the issue

Comment: oh . . the data type for `DATE` column is `integer` ?

Comment: yes, it gives this error  
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. Could you please help rewrite the query to take DATE as INT and in yyyymmdd format. We do not need any time column,

Answer (score 2):

- You should consider investing in a legitimate Date_Time table.

It makes comparing the official beginning and ending of the weeks MUCH easier and practical. And hey, you might even be able to use indexing!

However, there is another way. AS you shall see, `DATEPART` returns the ISO Month and Week we are looking for.

So provided our year is right, we now know where our boundaries are and can easily use an `IIF(<boolean_expression>, <true_expression>, <false_expression>)` statement inside of a `COUNT(<column>)`. `COUNT` ignores `NULL`s, so we set `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to `NULL`. :D

```
-- Note, I changed the column [Date] to [Dates]
DECLARE @Date INT
SET @Date = CAST(CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS VARCHAR(4) ) + '0101' AS INT)

SELECT  ISSUEDUSER--DATEPART(YYYY, CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10) ) )
      , COUNT( IIF(DATEDIFF(MM, CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10) ), GETDATE() ) = 0
           , 1
           , NULL) ) AS MONTHS
      , COUNT( IIF(DATEDIFF(WW, CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10) ), GETDATE() ) = 0
           , 1
           , NULL) ) AS Weeks
      , COUNT( IIF(DATEDIFF(DD, CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10) ), GETDATE() ) = 0
           , 1
           , NULL) ) AS Days
FROM    #BookReport
WHERE DATES >= @Date
GROUP BY ISSUEDUSER
--results    
ISSUEDUSER  MONTHS  Weeks   Days
A           3       3       1
B           1       1       1 
C           2       2       0
```

Note that you can expand the allowable date difference by adjusting the `boolean` statement! No extra coding required.

Also note that your examples actually only have one date that is not of the same Month, Week, or Day (within one day), although in my example I required Days to be of the same day as the query to make it look a bit different.

### Cool Observations:

- `DATE` by definition has no formatting and `DATEPART` can guess from a well-formed `Datetime` **string**, so there was no reason to double cast your Date column. However, if your pattern changes, you may need to add a `CONVERT`.
- `DATEPART` gives you the standard (ISO) Month and Week recognized, which means no Date_Time table required here. :)
- `DATEDIFF` is the magic here, and makes your `Boolean` statement REALLY easy to work with.
- Pretty slick, no?
- MSDN's page on [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) is worth a quick glance.

Comment: The only limitation on this formula is that the `Predicate` is not using a `SARGable` argument. That could be fixed easily enough, depending on the size of your database. Up to you.

Comment: Solved that fast. Use `CAST( CAST(SYSDATETIME AS VARCHAR(4) ) + '0101' AS INT)`. `SYSDATETIME` returns the year you are looking for, which makes the rest of this easy. In fact, I would use a `@variable` to embed this value before making the query. Anyone say `INDEX SEEK`? :D

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!